# why can I use a class as custom comparison criterion as a template argument to std::map without providing a class instance

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm reading the `std::map` part of *The C++ Standard Library* by Nicolai M. Josuttis.

Here is a simplified code which can show the question bother me a lot:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class MyCompare {
public:
    bool operator() (const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int, MyCompare> m {{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}, {"baz", 3}};
    for (const auto& p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I use my own `MyCompare` to show `m` how to sort elements.

My question is that, since `MyCompare::operator()` is an ordinary member function(I mean, it's not `static` or something else), we need an instance of `MyCompare` to call `operator()`, which means, to provide the address of the object.

But what is also clear that, there is no such thing in the code, and the code runs well.

Can anyone answer this for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This reference for the `std::map` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) might be useful to read. Pay attention to alternative 10.

Comment: You can provide it your own instance if you want. If you don't, it conveniently constructs an instance to use.

Comment: *We* don't need that instance, but the map does. The map can create that instance on its own since it knows what the type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison function object in the [map constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) is optional. You might want to pass it if a comparison type doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: funny that the constructor with `Compare()` default is even valid when there is no `Compare()`. c++ is weird :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's simple. A declaration doesn't create a default parameter value until a function with a default parameter is used.

Answer (score 5):

If we take a look at cppreference's documentation for [std::map constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map):

> ```cpp
> map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
>     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
>     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); (10) (since C++11)
> ```

The overload that accepts an initializer list also provides a default value for the comparison function. In this case, it will be a default-initialized instance of your `MyCompare` class.